# Regular expression to capture between spaces

Tags: regex, import.io

I have the following string:

```
Select SizesS M L XL
```

And I want to pull out the sizes immediately following 'Select Sizes', basically by capturing everything that isn't 'Select Sizes' with a space on one or both sides.
This has to be done by regex alone, as ImportIO doesn't support the use of methods.

This is what I have so far:

```
(?:Select Sizes)\w(\s\w)*
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: The capture groups must be: 'S' 'M' 'L' 'XL',

and its for Import IO, which is javascript I believe.

Comment: Is there an space between `S` and `Sizes`?

Comment: please add the js tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a pure regex solution if you would like to evaluate the same

```
(?<!Select\s)(?<=Sizes|\s)(\w+)
```

match all modifier `/g` is applied to above regex

result for the test string `Select SizesS M L XL`

MATCH 1

1. [12-13] `S`

MATCH 2

1. [14-15] `M`

MATCH 3

1. [16-17] `L`

MATCH 4

1. [18-20] `XL`

demo at [regex101.com](http://regex101.com/r/vT0eT3/2)

Answer (score 4):

You could use lookbehind,

```
(?<=Select Sizes)(.*)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/bL1cV0/6)

OR

```
Select Sizes(\S+)\s*(\S+)\s*(\S+)\s*(\S+)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/bL1cV0/7)

Four capturing groups are used to capture the non-space characters which are following the string `Select sizes`

OR

```
> "Select SizesS M L XL".split(/Select Sizes| /g)
[ '',
  'S',
  'M',
  'L',
  'XL' ]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try simple string operation: (if needed then use `trim()` as well)

```
"Select SizesS M L XL".substring(12).split(" ");
```

OR better use

```
"Select SizesS M L XL".substring("Select Sizes".length).split(" ");
```

output:

```
["S", "M", "L", "XL"]
```

---

If you are looking fore regex only using capturing groups then get the matched group from index 2 from below regex pattern:

```
(Select Sizes)?\s*(\w+)\s*
```

**Note:** I assume there is nothing behind the `Select Sizes` and there are only sizes in the given string.

Here is [demo](http://regex101.com/r/gH9wY6/1)